# Psql wrong date from timestamp

Tags: psql

cloud somebody explain to me why casting **timestamp** to **date** in **psql** gives me wrong value? I have in my db stored time stamp value **2016-12-04 00:05:09.748000** and my machine time is in **UTC**, and datatype in **psql** is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. If I did this,

> orders.completed::date

it gives me **2016-12-03**. Problem is that if i have some orders around midnight aggregate functions gives me wrong values. Is there some way how to solve it? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: try running code in my answer (ajusting TZ to needed to have midnihgt edge of course) does it change the date?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
(orders.completed::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles')::date;
```

You need to insert your timezone in query

Comment: Thank you, it works, but my problem will be somewhere else because it did not solve my problem. Aggregate functions still returns bad wrong values, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I can't reproduce it:

```
b=# set timezone to "GMT+10";
SET
b=# create table edge (t timestamptz);
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into edge select now();
INSERT 0 1
b=# select t::date, t from edge;
     t      |               t
------------+-------------------------------
 2016-12-08 | 2016-12-08 00:18:30.740132-10
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hm, that's odd. I run some test with this:
now() at TIME ZONE 'GMT+11' with result 2016-12-08 00:40:39.717069 and (now() at TIME ZONE 'GMT+11')::date with result 2016-12-07.

Comment: @inle so with my example it works as supposed? then check if you dont save date value somewhere and 5 minutes later (that is another day already) use the VALUE of yesterday